# truffleとOpenZeppelinを使ってropstenへmigrateと使用するアカウントについて

Tags: ethereum

ネット上で色々とサンプルがあり試しています

```
$ truffle migrate --network ropsten

Using network 'ropsten'.

Running migration: 2_deploy_my_token.js
  Deploying ccToken...
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful 
transactions manually.
insufficient funds for gas * price + value
```

とエラーになります

gasを払う必要があると理解しているのですが、そのアカウントの指定方法はあるのでしょうか?

`trruffle.js`に`from`を設定した場合は以下の通りです

```
var HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");
var mnemonic = process.env.ROPSTEN_MNEMONIC;
var accessToken = process.env.INFURA_ACCESS_TOKEN;

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    ropsten: {
      provider: function() {
        return new HDWalletProvider(
          mnemonic,
          "https://ropsten.infura.io/" + accessToken
        );
      },
      network_id: 3,
      gas: 6000000,
      from: "0xaebc17de97aa748dda2cf8******************"
    }   
  }
};
```

実行すると、

```
$ truffle migrate --network ropsten
Using network 'ropsten'.

Running migration: 2_deploy_my_token.js
   Deploying ccToken...
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Unknown address - unable to sign transaction for this address: "0xaebc17de97aa748dda2cf8******************"
```

エラーになりました

`from`のアカウントのロック解除はどうするのかという疑問もあります
migrateする場合、ローカルでgethを実行(migrateの際にロック解除)する必要があったりするのでしょうか?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました

infra.ioへの登録をしていなかったためです

`truffle.js`は以下の通り

```
var HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");
var mnemonic = "12個のmnemonic";
var accessToken = "infra.io 登録時に付与されたもの";

module.exports = {
    networks: {
        ropsten: {
            provider: function() {
                return new HDWalletProvider(
                mnemonic,
                "https://ropsten.infura.io/" + accessToken
                );
            },
            network_id: 3,
            gas: 6000000,
            from: "mnemonicに対応するアドレス"
        }   
    }
};
```

新たに発生した疑問は、`var mnemonic`以外使えないのかなと
パスワードでアドレスつくった場合はどうするのだろうかという点です
要点からずれていると思うので一旦クローズにします